# Accessing Ember controller attributes from a controller

Tags: ember.js

I have the following controller:

```
App.ShowController = Ember.Controller.expend({
   buttonTitle: 'Create'
});
```

And the following template `show.handlebars`

```
<a href='#'>{{buttonTitle}}</a>
```

but the text is not rendering. Is there a special call to access the attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when a view is displayed (via the Router), the context of the view is automatically set to the controller, so there should be nothing to do special.

Here is an example, where the `MyApp.IndexController` is automatically set as the context of the `IndexView` (and its template is the `index` template):

```
MyApp = Ember.Application.create({});

MyApp.Router = Ember.Router.extend();

MyApp.Router.map(function(match) {
  match('/').to('index');
});

MyApp.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  buttonTitle: "create"
});
```

The template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{buttonTitle}}
</script>
```

And you could try it [on this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pASLs/).

N.B.: I'm using Ember v1.0.0-pre.2-239 here. There are some changes to do for upgrading this example to master

Comment: I forgot that I was actually rendering the template with the `render` helper from the `show` template. So the context was actually changing.